# Why isn't the result of an OpenQuery refreshing?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get some data from the Active Directory in SQL. I use the code:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery 
( 
ADSI, 
'SELECT  objectGUID, objectSID, employeeID, lastLogon, mobile, telephoneNumber, mail,  department, givenName, sn, displayname,  sAmAccountName
FROM ''LDAP://DC=mycompany''    
where  objectClass = ''user''
and sAmAccountName = ''testuser'''  
)
```

My problem is that the value i receive for lastLogon isn't refreshing. It is possible that the other values aren't also refreshing, however i can't say this for sure, because in the other data there is no change, but the lastLogon value should be updated when i lock my computer and log in.

Does anyone have any idee why is this, and how can i solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lastLogon` attribute reflects the last interactive logon, not the last network-based logon

More info found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939899)

This is some excellent information from [this site](http://www.microsoftnow.com/2007/06/making-sense-out-of-lastlogon-user.html)

> Another twist: Active Directory does NOT replicate the LastLogon
>   attribute across domain controllers. So in order to get an accurate
>   value, you need to obtain the LastLogon value for the same user from
>   all your domain controllers and accept the value that is highest.

Comment: if i make a query from a C++ application then it is updated. Why is that?

Comment: @kampi: IIRC, An ADSI linked server hits the same DC, not the domain itself.